# Example of layouts for 4 buttons and text under them

Tags: android, android-layout

Is there any example of `xml` for the activity which consists of four buttons (two in a row) and a text under them?

Somethings like this, but less buttons.
[image]

Comment: Do you want a layout file for it?

Comment: A mockup image would help us understand what your goal is.

Comment: Called gridview and can be done by reading the documentation or the samples on the official page... @androidnoob: at least try to do it by yourself... if you are stuck somewhere, we will help you, but we don't develop a layout for you...

Comment: @WarrenFaith, I didn't mean that, thanks for the reference to gridview.

Comment: This is GridView with elements: vertical LinearLayout containing ImageView and TextView

Comment: its still the best solution... more generic than the solution provided by Rejinderi

Answer (score 1):

try editing this! made it in 2 mintues haha got to go~ good luck and cya

```
  <LinearLayout
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:orientation="horizontal">
  <Button
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_weight="1"
  android:text="Button 1">
  </Button>
   <Button
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_weight="1"
  android:text="Button 2">
  </Button>
  </LinearLayout>
  <LinearLayout
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:orientation="horizontal">
  <Button
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_weight="1"
  android:text="Button 3">
  </Button>
   <Button
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_weight="1"
  android:text="Button 4">
  </Button>
  </LinearLayout>
  <EditText
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:text="I love some text here!"
  ></EditText>
</LinearLayout>
```